# creating selectbox using jquery adding multiple select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am posting html and jquery code. Using JQuery 1.9.1.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {

        var search = $('#search').val();

        if (search.length > 2) {
            var s = $('<select />');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchuser",
                cache: false,
                data: 'search=' + $("#search").val(),
                success: function (response) {

                    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        $('<option />', {
                            value: value,
                            text: value
                        }).appendTo(s);
                    });

                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }

            });
        }

        s.appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <form>
      <input id="search" type="text"  name="search" />
    </form>
    <div id="info"></div>

    <div id="other">
      Trigger the handler
    </div>
```

and the above code is creating multiple select elements I understood that it is due to ajax calls but how can i avoid creating additional select elemnts or suggest me how can i convert text box to select item

Comment: When you post code, giving a jsfiddle link is always a good way to get faster answers :)

Comment: i can not because i am having a request which is coming from database so it will post error, but just for clear understanding of java script and html i am posting my jsfiddel link http://jsfiddle.net/Pkgje/

Comment: in jsfiddle you have some nice echo framework for ajax request, i will post you one

Comment: there you have it, a fiddle that will spoof the ajax request : [http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/VLvDu/](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/VLvDu/)

Comment: i kept my java script and body here http://jsfiddle.net/kPjTZ/1/ i am not understanding why ajax is not called can you help me @TecHunter

Comment: almost there... You need to look for [the remote datasource example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote), if you really want to use `$.ajax` when getting data from your source read the [JSONP example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Comment: but the problem i am not able to call the url (ajax is not working)

Comment: first please read and explore the example! give me fiddle to show me you actually tried something from the example. and for your issue of `$.ajax` not working, you simply forgot to include JQuery + JQueryUI in fiddle. Please try harder

Comment: How to add JQuery+JQueryUI in fiddle i am very sorry if i am troubling you @TecHunter

Comment: please search first. look into jsfiddle UI. little hint it's in the upper left corner

Comment: As you suggested i added JQUERY+JQUERYUI js in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kPjTZ/13/ can you suggest me where it is going wrong

Comment: @TecHunter can give your mailid

Comment: no you did not :/ here with JQuery libs http://jsfiddle.net/kPjTZ/14/. I suggest you try, you will fail 10 times maybe but you might learn some good tricks. If you really can't do it (I mean after trying, debugging, trying again etc...) then post another one. this post is answered and should not extend further more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the select element only once then append everything OR you can use `.replaceWith`.

If you don't especially need to create the select element on the fly it's even better to put in directly in the html :

```
<body>

    <form>
      <input id="search" type="text"  name="search" />
    </form>
    <div id="info"></div>

    <div id="other">
      Trigger the handler
    </div>
    <select id="searchSelectTarget">
    </select>

</body>
```

While in your JS be carefull with Ajax, it's asynchronous so most of the time the `.appendTo`will be executed before ajax returns :

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {

    var search = $('#search').val();

    if (search.length > 2) {
        var $select = $('#searchSelectTarget').empty(); //just to reset the content
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchuser",
            cache: false,
            data: 'search=' + $("#search").val(),
            success: function (response) {

                $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                    $('<option />', {
                        value: value,
                        text: value
                    }).appendTo($select);
                });
//    s.appendTo('body'); this one would have moved here but you don't need it anymore
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }

        });
    }


});
```

Comment: thank you very much @TecHunter it is working fine but can i convert the input tag to selectbox

Comment: i want to create a selectbox with same name and id as input field can i

Comment: @user1654561 you mean when your request comes back delete the input and replace it with the select?

Comment: yeah exactly as my request has a list of elements show that i can show them as suggestion to the user to select

Comment: what i want to do exactly is i want the user to enter text as well as select from combobox @TecHunter

Comment: what i want to do exactly is i want the user to enter text as well as select from combobox as shown in this website http://www.redbus.in/ @TecHunter

Comment: aaahhhh then all you need is [autocomplete from jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). I will let you read and if you have any issue ask :)

Comment: thanks for the support @TecHunter . I am not able to understand how to call ajax in default functionality http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/